# MissingMethodException: No signature of method: getBean() after recompilation

Tags: grails, groovy, vaadin

[This code](https://github.com/ondrej-kvasnovsky/grails-vaadin-plugin/blob/master/source-code/VaadinGrailsPlugin.groovy#L113) adds getBean() methods to the classes we are using:

```
    clazz.metaClass.getBean = { String name ->
        return VaadinUtils.getBean(name)
    }
    clazz.metaClass.getBean = { Class type ->
        return VaadinUtils.getBean(type)
    }
```

It works without problem when the application is started and it also survives few recompilations. Recompilation is done [like this](https://github.com/ondrej-kvasnovsky/grails-vaadin-plugin/blob/master/source-code/VaadinGrailsPlugin.groovy#L281):

```
def reloadedClass = application.classLoader.loadClass(vaadinGrailsClass.clazz.name)
```

After few recompilations, it says that getBean() method is missing and the exception is thrown (so one has to restart and redeploy the application under development).

```
Caused by MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
com.myapp.SaveIssueDetailListener.getBean() is applicable for argument types: 
(java.lang.Class) values: [class agiletool.core.IssueService]
Possible solutions: getClass(), getForm(), getAt(java.lang.String)

->> 30   buttonClick in com.myapp.SaveIssueDetailListener$$ENRHmYFM
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
512  receiveEvent in com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod
164  fireEvent . . . . . in com.vaadin.event.EventRouter
1219     fireEvent in com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent
550  fireClick . . . . . in com.vaadin.ui.Button
217  changeVariables in ''
1451     changeVariables . . in com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager
1399     handleVariableBurst in ''
1318     handleVariables . . in ''
763  doHandleUidlRequest in ''
296  handleUidlRequest . in com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.CommunicationManager
501  service in com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet
191  service . . . . . . in com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.GrailsAwareApplicationServlet
886  runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
908  run . . . . . . . . in ''
680  run in java.lang.Thread
```

This is how we call the getBean() method:

```
public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
    UserService userService = getBean(UserService) //...
```

Any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs only in old versions of plugin for Vaadin 6. Vaadin plugin (for Vaadin 7) for Grails has been done from scratch and this issue doesn't exist there.

More info can be found in related [JIRA issue](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPVAADIN-14).

More details about new Vaadin can be found on http://vaadinongrails.com/